# Django - Static file, image, wont appear

Tags: django, image, static

I'm learning django. It was working in the beginning of my project, but now imgs from static just dont appear.
I've try to run `collecstatic`, work with `STATIC_ROOT`, other images and so on.

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/upload/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upload')
```

**Home.html**

```
{% load static %}
<img scr="{% static 'img/cart-icon.png' %}">
```

[Files dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUWNf.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'img/cart-icon.png' %}">
```

src not scr